# Multiple controls with the same ID '' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**update:**

here is what i observed:

```
if i get    org.Registrations.Count = 1 then 
    txtBox.ID   "_registration0_0"  string
....
....
```

if i get org.Registrations.Count = 2 then its act strange

```
txtBox.ID   "_registration2_0"  
txtBox.ID   "_registration2_1"


after that i starts again with _registration2_0
```

ps: i dont have problem if the count = 1

**end update**

the error messages clearly says that i am trying to have duplicate id but below is where i am creating dynamic textbox, do you see whats wrong in my code?

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   Students org = (namespace.Students )(e.Row.DataItem);

   foreach (Registration reg in org.Registrations)
   {
      int _count = org.Registrations.Count;
      for (int rowId = 0; rowId < _count; rowId++)
      {
         TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
         txtBox.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;
         txtBox.Text = reg.Name;
         e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code, is it returning unique ID's for each column?  I am concerned with Row.RowIndex and thats why I am asking.  Debug the code and place watch values for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont need the `for` loop inside the `foreach` .. its working as expected... thats why  was executing twice.

```
foreach (Registration reg in org.Registrations) 
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you have multiple org.Registrations you could end up with duplicate ids.
Look at usage of the test variable below:

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   Students org = (namespace.Students )(e.Row.DataItem);
   int test =0;
   foreach (Registration reg in org.Registrations)
   {
      test++;
      int _count = org.Registrations.Count;
      for (int rowId = 0; rowId < _count; rowId++)
      {
         TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
         txtBox.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId + "_" + test.ToString();
         txtBox.Text = reg.Name;
         e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);
     }
   }
}
```